# Updating my table via EF 4.0Entity Exception occured

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

i writed these codes to update my whole table re order my jobseqno:

```
      protected void Update()
        {
            MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities ();

                var qry = ctx.MyTable.Where(q => q.workorder == "100001076").OrderBy(q => q.id);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = qry;
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var item in qry)
                {
                    i++;
                    item.jobseqno = i.ToString();
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                }

        }
```

How to update my whole table. i give new number collection jobseqno. But Error occured:

#### EntityException was unhandled

An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details:

Exception : New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Comment: Well? So what is the inner exception?

Comment: inner exception :  New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Comment: and that ctx.SaveChanges() call should be called after the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2010/07/08/entity-framework-4-and-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-there-are-other-threads-running-in-the-session-exception.aspx) blog post, the solution seems to be to store the elements you get from MyTable into an array, as opposed to working with the IEnumerable result directly. Try this:

```
var qry =
   ctx.MyTable
       .Where(q => q.workorder == "100001076")
       .OrderBy(q => q.id)
       .ToArray<MyTable>; // save it as a local array
```